# Internet Explorer History count

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, browser-history

How can i get the count of internet explorer history? I am able to achive it using Shell.Application in vb but can't in delphi.
I found a code with "CLSID_CUrlHistory" which showing all cache entries.

---

I tried to convert the same, but I am missing something, please look into the following answer and correct me where I went wrong

```
Procedure ListIeHistory;

Const
HISTORY_LIST = 34;
ITEM_NAME = 0;
ITEM_DATE = 2;

var
ShellSession        : OleVariant;
ShellHistory        : OleVariant;
ShellEntry          : OleVariant;
ShellHistoryFolder  : OleVariant;
ShellCollection     : OleVariant;
oEnum               : IEnumvariant;
iValue              : LongWord;

Begin
    result:='';
    ShellSession:= CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
    ShellHistory    := ShellSession.Namespace(HISTORY_LIST);
    ShellHistoryFolder:= ShellHistory.self;
    ShellCollection  := ShellHistory.Items;
    oEnum         := IUnknown(ShellCollection._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;

    while oEnum.Next(1, ShellEntry, iValue) = 0 do
        begin
                 form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(vartostr(ShellEntry.Name));
        end;
end;
```

***Edited by TLama***

Please note, that this code has no error handling (I'm busy right now), so take it as an inspiration. But are you sure it is what you want, I think if you'll follow the code from my answer and filter some items (most probably period) you will get the same.

This browses the `C:\Users\TLama\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History` directory, so I think you are missing some history items (not me ;-) but I don't have time to study where the history items are taken from.

***Note that to use the [`IUrlHistoryStg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface is the right way to go, not this***.

```
uses
  ComObj;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  URL: string;
  Visited: string;
  I, J, K: Integer;
  Shell: OleVariant;
  Item: OleVariant;
  SiteFolder: OleVariant;
  SiteItem: OleVariant;
  PageFolder: OleVariant;
  PageItem: OleVariant;
  Folder: OleVariant;
const
  ITEM_NAME = 0;
  ITEM_DATE = 2;
  HISTORY_LIST = 34;
begin
  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  Folder := Shell.NameSpace(HISTORY_LIST);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Location: ' + Folder.Self.Path);

  for I := 0 to Folder.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Item := Folder.Items.Item(I);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Period: ' + Item.Name);

    if Item.IsFolder then
    begin
      SiteFolder := Item.GetFolder;
      for J := 0 to SiteFolder.Items.Count - 1 do
      begin
        SiteItem := SiteFolder.Items.Item(J);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Site: ' + SiteItem.Name);

        if SiteItem.IsFolder then
        begin
          PageFolder := SiteItem.GetFolder;
          for K := 0 to PageFolder.Items.Count - 1 do
          begin
            PageItem := PageFolder.Items.Item(K);
            URL := PageFolder.GetDetailsOf(PageItem, ITEM_NAME);
            Visited := PageFolder.GetDetailsOf(PageItem, ITEM_DATE);
            Memo1.Lines.Add('URL: ' + URL + '; Visited: ' + Visited);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The [Embedded Web Browser Components Pack (aka TEmbeddedWB)](http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html) has an Url History object, where you can view and enumerate the IE history list. The component is Delphi5 to XE compatible.

Comment: Why do you want the count?  This is a complex thing to deal with.  Please explain what you're actually trying to do and I may be able to suggest the correct course of action.

Comment: You can use IUrlHistoryStg::EnumUrls() to enumerate the history.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767720(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jeffamaphone, it seems it returns the same (or very similar) as the `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry` and `FindNextUrlCacheEntry` functions. I can't verify it now, but as soon as I have some time, I'll check it.

Comment: Yes, it does.  It would be strange if it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Total rewrite based on [`jeffamaphone's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74815/jeffamaphone) suggestion to use the [`IUrlHistoryStg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. It seems it returns the same or very similar result as the code before this update (I didn't verified that).

Here is the code which should print out all URLs in Internet Explorer history for the current user into the memo box and then show a message box with count of them (it's easy to modify this code to only count the entries):

```
uses
  ComObj, ActiveX;

type
  TStatURL = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    pwcsUrl: LPWSTR;
    pwcsTitle: LPWSTR;
    ftLastVisited: FILETIME;
    ftLastUpdated: FILETIME;
    ftExpires: FILETIME;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
  end;
  IEnumStatURL = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{3C374A42-BAE4-11CF-BF7D-00AA006946EE}']
    function Next(celt: ULONG; var elt: TStatURL; var pceltFetched: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Reset: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Clone(out ppenum: IEnumStatURL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetFilter(poszFilter: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IUrlHistoryStg = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{3C374A41-BAE4-11CF-BF7D-00AA006946EE}']
    function AddUrl(pocsUrl: PWideChar; pocsTitle: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DeleteUrl(pocsUrl: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function QueryUrl(pocsUrl: PWideChar; dwFlags: DWORD; var lpSTATURL: TStatURL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function BindToObject(pocsUrl: PWideChar; var riid: TIID; out ppvOut: Pointer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function EnumUrls(out ppenum: IEnumStatURL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

const
  CLSID_CUrlHistory: TGUID = '{3C374A40-BAE4-11CF-BF7D-00AA006946EE}';

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Cardinal;
  StatURL: TStatURL;
  EnumStatURL: IEnumStatURL;
  UrlHistoryStg: IUrlHistoryStg;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    UrlHistoryStg := CreateComObject(CLSID_CUrlHistory) as IUrlHistoryStg;
    if UrlHistoryStg.EnumUrls(EnumStatURL) = S_OK then
    begin
      while EnumStatURL.Next(1, StatURL, I) = S_OK do
      begin
        if I = 1 then
          Memo1.Lines.Add(StatURL.pwcsUrl);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Memo1.Lines.Count) + ' URLs found in history');
end;
```

Interesting is that nobody mentioned in the documentation of the [`IEnumSTATURL.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method that you have to pass to the `celt` parameter value of 1 otherwise you will stick into the infinite loop.

Comment: Hi TLana, the history contents are 354 when (when we click on view history in i.e.) my vb output is giving the exact 354 as result. But in Delphi, showing all the entries in thousands. In my system instead of 354 it is showing 3164

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/28696fd5-2a90-4766-9b96-d4bc38c9db12

Comment: Please look into the above vb code link it is showing the exact count. Help me to convert this